# Optimal Strategy for a classic guessing game

Tags: probability

I found similar links to the following game, but none were identical to what I am being asked.

Game: you have a set of integers $\left\{1,2,...n\right\}$. Host picks at random one of the numbers and gives you $k$ chances to guess it. After each guess the host says "higher," "lower," or "correct."

Question: **Prove that if $n\leq 2^k-1$ then there is a strategy that guarantees you will guess the number by the $k$th guess**

My solution:

Strategy: Guess half way each time

Example: if n=100 and host=70, my first two picks would end up being 50 (reply from host: higher) and then 75

I then got by the $k^{th}$ guess that the probability of guessing the number is $\frac{2^{k-1}}{n}\geq\frac{2^{k-1}}{2^k-1}>\frac{1}{2}$

This strategy only guarantees better than $\frac{1}{2}$

Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain how you got your probability of guessing the number on the $k^{th}$ step? I suggest going beyond 75 in your example. What would you guess next?

Comment: My process was the first guess has probability $\frac{1}{n}$ where I pick the center. Thus my second guess has probability $\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2^1}{n}$ Thus my $k^{th}$ guess has probability $\frac{2^{k-1}}{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Theorem*. When $n = 2^k -1 $ you can guess the right number in $k$ guesses with complete certainty, for all $k \in \mathbb N$.
>
> *proof*. When $k=1$ the theorem follows immediately. Now suppose that $n = 2^{k+1} - 1$. Now guess the number $2^k$, and we are left with at most $2^k - 1$ unknown numbers, which can be guessed in $k$ steps, hence a total of $k+1$ steps.

Now for all arguments where $n < 2^{k} -1 $ just use some dummy numbers in the argumentation.

Comment: You know what when I read back over the question, I started to see they just wanted me to prove that such a strategy exists, not necessarily come up with one (which is what you did). I do believe the system of cutting in half is what is used though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we use binary search algorithm with guesses lower or higher on every turn, the maximum  number of guesses that is requried to guess a number between 1-n is $\lceil\log_{2}n\rceil$ and this must be less than k to guarantee that we guess the number wuthin k guesses.  So

$\lceil\log_{2}n\rceil\le k$

$\lfloor\log_{2}n\rfloor +1 \le k$

$ n\le 2^{k-1}$